# Qt - Add two numbers

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmainwindow, qtgui

I can't get this to work. Anyone knows how to make it work?

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    int sum1 = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();
    int sum2 = ui->lineEdit_2->text().toInt();

    ui->label_4->setText(sum1 + sum2);
}
```

Error:

> C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Mellemrubrik\mainwindow.cpp:26: error: C2664: 'QLabel::setText' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'const QString &'
>   Reason: cannot convert from 'int' to 'const QString'
>   No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

Comment: Please tell us what problems you are experiencing. It is not easy for us to help when the problem description is "Doesn't work" :)

Comment: Not enough jquery. =) If you can write this post, why you can't understand the compiler message? "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'const QString &'" - so compiler can't convert your integer to Qt QString. You need to convert from int to QString explicitly.

Comment: As it is written in the error message, it cannot convert from int to string, you need to cast the (sum1 + sum2) to a string like the solutions mentioned below, using QString::number

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can convert multiple numeric types to QStrings like so:

```
int val1, val2;
QString result = QString("val1=%1 val2=%2 sum=%3").arg(val1).arg(val2).arg(val1+val2);
```

But for numbers, this is also possible:

```
int val1, val2;
QString result = QString::number(val1+val2);
```

You can see Qt's [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html) for more info!

Comment: What are the generic "quantities" not being numbers here? QString::number() is basically equivalent in functionality, and more concise (and more performant probably, too). So I'd always use the second variant.

Comment: The advantage to .arg() in some cases is your ability to chain them. I just updated my example to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
int v1,v2;
v1=ui->lineEdit->text().toInt():
v2=ui->lineEdit_2->text().toInt()
QString result = QString::number(v1+v2);
ui->label->setText(result);
```

Comment: you should try and add a brief textual description to your code block. Perhaps taking "You can try this" out of the code block, and expanding slightly on the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Would `setNum` as shown below do?

```
int v1,v2;
v1=ui->lineEdit->text().toInt():
v2=ui->lineEdit_2->text().toInt()
ui->label->setNum(v1+v2);
```